# Price rule for customer group

Tags: magento-1.7

We want to offer certain customer groups a discount on up to 3 items. We want to offer this discount on a 'per year' basis. is this possible to do?

Magento would have to track the customer's purchases each time they order. Once they get to the point of ordering 3 (of a certain category) the discount would be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with plain-old Magento.

Using a **Shopping Cart Price Rule**, set the customer group and the max # of uses to 3, with an expiration date for 1 year from now. Albeit this isn't a 'rolling' 1 year term for **each individual customer** (would require a custom module) but you *could* set all of them to expire by Jan 1, and start afresh at the new year. See below:

[image]

Comment: Right, but that would simply allow them to use the coupon 3 times. Then they would have to be limited to purchase 1 item each time. What if they want to purchase 2 items on their first order and 1 item on their second order? Or if they want to order 1 item on the first order and 2 items on the second order?

Comment: Correct - it's 3 separate uses, unlimited number of items per order.

Comment: So you want 3 items limit lifetime??

Comment: Your requirements are too complex to code within the realm of this forum. In the meantime I suggest that your shopping cart rule limits the discount to a maximum of 3 items to prevent abuse. Alternatively, create 3 separate coupon codes, each usable 1 time by each customer, and those 3 codes are good only for 1 year. Each code has a rule to apply to 1 item per purchase only. If they want their combined discount they could purchase 3 times. You could install a multicoupon extension to allow for 1 purch. Otherwise the scope of work you define is too large for StackExchange. Hire a developer.

Comment: Okay, we'll maybe try a multi-coupon extension